# How to check if you are logged into Facebook in the GEM koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala

The application is written in Ruby on Rails, using Koala GEM to support Facebook auth.

How to check if a given user. log on to our app now.

I have a code to login

```
def index
  @oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new (APP_ID, SECRET, URL_US)
  @a = @oauth.url_for_oauth_code (:permissions => "email")
  redirect_to @a
end
```

I would if I worked Koala already logged as such it calls redirect_to client_app_path and how not to redirect_to @a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
def index
  @oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new (APP_ID, SECRET, URL_US)
  facebook_user_id = @oauth.get_user_from_cookies(cookies)
  @a = @oauth.url_for_oauth_code (:permissions => "email")
  if facebook_user_id.present?
    redirect_to client_app_path
  else
    redirect_to @a
  end
end
```

I am not sure of the output of `@oauth.get_user_from_cookies(cookies)` if you are not connected to Facebook, maybe it's an empty string instead of nil. If so, change the `if` statement to redirect properly if connected or not.

Seen here: https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/OAuth in *Cookie Parsing*